# How to use transforms.FiveCrop() outside the DataLoader?

Tags: pytorch

I have a dataloader that returns a batch of shape `torch.Size([bs, c, h, w])` where `bs=4, c=1,and (h, w=128)`. Now I want to apply some custom transformations to the returned batch. **Note** that I can not apply transformations in the Dataloader as I need to feed the returned batch as is to one network and a transformed one to another network.

More specifically, I want to apply the following transformations to the returned batch:

```
1. CenterCrop(100)
2. FiveCrop(16)
3. Resize(128)
4. ToTensor()
5. Normalize([0.5], [0.5])
```

I have created a function to achieve the following task as follows:

```
# DataLoader code
#
#
orig_img = next(iter(DataLoader))
patches = get_patches(orig_img)

def get_patches(orig_img):
    # orig_img.shape = torch.Size([4, 1, 128, 128])
    images = [TF.to_pil_image(x) for x in orig_img.cpu()]
    resized_imgs = []

    for img in images:
        img = transforms.CenterCrop(100)(img)
        five_crop = transforms.FiveCrop(64)(img)
        f_crops = transforms.Lambda(lambda crops: torch.stack([transforms.Normalize([0.5], [0.5])(transforms.ToTensor()(transforms.Resize(128)(crop))) for crop in crops]))(five_crop)
        resized_imgs.append(f_crops)
    return resized_imgs
```

The problem right now is that when I get the resized_imgs list, every tensor inside it looses the batch size dimension i.e. `resized_imgs[0].shape =  torch.Size([ncrops, c, h, w]) (4d)` whereas, I expect the shape to be `torch.Size([bs, ncrops, c, h, w]) (5d)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data loader will return a tensor of shape `(bs, c, h, w)`. Therefore `orig_img` is shaped the same way and iterating through it will provide you with a tensor `img` shaped as `(c, h, w)`. Applying `FiveCrop` will create an additional dimension such that `five_crop` is shaped `(5, c, h, w)`. Then `f_crops` will be shaped `(5, c, 128, 128)`. Finally, the tensor is appended with the others in `resized_imgs` (the *list* containing the different patched images). All in all resized_imgs contains `bs` elements since `orig_img.size(0) = bs`, and each element is a tensor shaped `(5, c, 128, 128)` (five patches per image) as we've described above.

Another way of writing this function would be:

```
def get_patches(orig_img):
    # orig_img.shape = (4, 1, 128, 128)

    img_t = T.Compose([T.ToPILImage(),
                       T.CenterCrop(100), 
                       T.FiveCrop(64)])
    patch_t = T.Compose([T.Resize(128),
                         T.ToTensor(),
                         T.Normalize([0.5], [0.5])])
    
    resized_imgs = []

    for img in orig_img:
        five_crop = img_t(img)
        f_crops = torch.stack(list(map(patch_t, five_crop)))
        resized_imgs.append(f_crops)
    return torch.stack(resized_imgs)
```

The last line will stack all image patches into a single tensor of shape `(bs, 5, c, 128, 128)`.

Comment: When I use your function I get ```TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'> on line f_crops = torch.stack(list(map(patch_t, five_crop)))```

Comment: What was your input type in this case?

Comment: orig_img is a batch of tensors from the datalaoder. I didn't change anything.

Comment: I fixed it. We need to reorder the patch_t transforms in such a way that we first Resize(), then ToTensor(), and finally Normalize(). It looks like this order does matter.

Comment: yes you need to edit your answer as follows:    

     patch_t = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(128),
                         transforms.ToTensor(),
                         transforms.Normalize([0.5], [0.5])])